# Print multiple of 7 between 53 to 96

Tags: c#

I want to print multiple of 7 between 53 to 96

**Code:**

```
int tbl = 0;
while(!(tbl > 53) || !(tbl < 96))
{
   tbl = tbl + 7;
   while(tbl > 53 && tbl < 96)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(tbl);
      tbl = tbl + 7;
   }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

Output should be: 56, 63, 70, 77, 84, 91
It should stop at 91, but it is not stopping at 91

Comment: If you want to check for multiples of seven, it's easier to use `%` (mod) in a for loop. Your code is harder to read.

Comment: You could use a debugger, step through your code, inspect variable values and find out what's going on.

Comment: @UweKeim Already did

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very basic approach

```
int tbl=53;
while  (tbl < 96)
{
   if (tbl % 7 == 0)
      Console.WriteLine(tbl);

   tbl++;
}
```

Comment: Yes but it is showing you can accept answer in 10 minutes

Answer (score 3):

This is the best and the fastest way to do this, when you hit a number which is divisible by 7, you continue to increment by 7 not by 1

```
int tbl = 53;

while  (tbl < 96)
{
   if (tbl % 7 == 0){
      Console.WriteLine(tbl);
      tbl+=7;
      continue;
   }
   tbl++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we want to print out *every* `7`th item, `for` loop seems to be the *simplest choice*:

```
int start = 53;
int stop = 96;

for (int tbl = (start / 7 + (start % 7 == 0 ? 0 : 1)) * 7; tbl < stop; tbl += 7)
   Console.WriteLine(tbl);

Console.ReadLine();
```

If `53` value is *fixed* we can precompute the start value: `(53 / 7 + (53 % 7 == 0 ? 0 : 1)) * 7 == (7 + 1) * 7 == 56`:

```
for (int tbl = 56; tbl < 96; tbl += 7) 
  Console.WriteLine(tbl); 

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score -1):

It need to be `&&` in the first while loop instead of `||`